# Good framework for a web application for graphical query interface?

Tags: graphical-programming

I want to develop a web application allowing the user to graphically build and execute queries. Having essentially no knowledge about the hundreds of web app frameworks that seem to proliferate out there, I turn to your expert opinion and good taste. It should be:

- well-equipped to handle graphical objects
- easy to interconnect with DB (could be MySQL, DB2 or other)
- easy to learn for someone who painstakingly cranked out some swing GUIs years ago, but now essentially uses Python and R and MATLAB :)
- preferably permissive open source licensed

Any tutorials and do's and dont's concerning web app development are also very welcome.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

use the symfony php framework in php codeing. very easy to handle.
http://www.symfony-project.org/

Comment: That looks fairly nice, just watched the ajax screencast. The only downside is that I know zero php at this point.

Answer (score 1):

I'd prefer Rails, but if you are fluent in Python, then you might try Django.

Comment: Django looks interestingly simple in terms of setting up the back end. I haven't found how it would help me with the graphics though.